# Is Docker remove Access-Control-Allow-Oring header?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

In a local environment, when the React app sends a publish request to Spring boot, it normally responds, but when Spring boot is made into an image and run as a container, the client receives net:ERR_FAILED 200 and CORS errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJgei.png)

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY build/libs/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I don't know why.

Comment: Such CORS errors usually indicate another underlying error that let to the server not being able to set these CORS headers. For example, if the server was not able to respond at all or did not even receive the request. In your screenshot, it appears like there is a "Network Error". Could you maybe further investigate that error? How are you making the container accessible from localhost (for example, using docker compose or docker run)?

Comment: Use docker run.

Comment: I solved it! I forgot to build to jar...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.